# Should there be a transactional class when using Spring @Transactional Annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations, transactional

I understand that @Transactional belongs to the Service layer, however is it good practices to make a class dedicated specifically for @Transactional operations?
The purpose of this is to control/call multiple DAOs to help complete a task and return values to the service class.

Is there any advantage of doing so? Or should I just simply do everything inside my service class instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt to focus on service purpose. It will be your guideline to decide where each rule should be. If perhaps you must compose multiple services into one transaction, then propagate the transaction. You don`t need to create another class just to group multiple calls to DAOs.